# Overload typecast to a user-defined type

Tags: c++

In C++, is it possible to overload a type cast (like you can with primitive types) that converts your type to another user-defined type, such as a class?

If so, how?

Comment: Yes, using the exact same syntax as for built-in types. If it doesn't work for you, show us your code.

Comment: It's all explained here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator (in a surprisingly clear manner).

Comment: Do you mean this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator?

Answer (score 0):

Just define the [cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) like:

```
class Dest {
};
class Src {
public:
    operator Dest()
    {   
        return Dest();
    }   
};
```